Strange behavior of the asyncio queue
I came across a strange behavior of the asyncio queue when the get() method does not wait for messages if the queue is empty.
The code below uses a simple class to work with a queue. I just run the start() method, which runs the private __send() method, in which we are waiting for messages from the queue.
Messages should be queued later using the put() method of the class.
I know that the asyncio queue is not thread-safe, but threads are not used.
import asyncio

class MessageQueue:
  def __init__(self):
    self.proc = None
    self.queue = asyncio.Queue()
  async def start(self):
      self.proc = asyncio.create_task(self.__send())
  async def stop(self):
    if self.proc is not None:
      self.proc.cancel()
  async def put(self, mobj):
    await self.queue.put(mobj)
  async def __send(self):
    logger.info('Starting queue.')
    while True:
      try:
#        if not self.queue.empty():
          msg = await self.queue.get()
          logger.info(msg)
      except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f'Error sending the message: {e}')


async def launch():
  queue = MessageQueue()
  await asyncio.gather(queue.start())

asyncio.run(launch())


The documentation says that the get() method should wait if the queue is empty. But in fact, I get an error immediately after launching.
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='message_queue' coro=<MessageQueue.start() done, defined at...
To make this code work, I have to check the queue for emptiness before trying to receive a message (a line with a comment in the code above). It seems to me that this approach is wrong.
Please tell me what my mistake is and how to do it right.

The problem has nothing to do with the queue. The main function of your asyncio program creates a message queue in line1, then it creates a task running queue.start() and waits for it in line2. The queue.start() has just one line (that line calls create_task), so it finishes really quickly and the await asyncio.gather(...) is done. There is no line3, so the program exits.
async def launch():
  queue = MessageQueue()               # line1
  await asyncio.gather(queue.start())  # line2

During the cleanup, the asyncio complains about the unfinished task.
To fix the problem, do not return to asyncio.run until the program has finished its work. What it means exactly depends on the program, of course.
Note: asyncio.gather is usally called to gather results of multiple tasks.
